# AS400 locks unused files

Tags: c#, .net, db2

I'm creating a windows service in C# for synchronize SQL to DB2 database.
I used IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries nuget package.
I created a query for read data in DB2 table called "PCIMPF".
In AS400, I found the file PCIMPF is used from the query.
It is correct but I found used another file, called "PC05L" not called in my query.
is it possible if i don't used this file?

I tried stop the service and the file "PC05L" unlocked.
I tried delete the file, and my service stopped without error.

```
    public string GetCodeOfDdt(iDB2Connection cn, string processCode, string OrderCode)
    {
        iDB2Command cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
        iDB2DataReader reader;
        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT NRBLCI FROM REM5DAT.PCIMPF WHERE ORPR='{OrderCode}' AND CDFA='{processCode}'";

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            reader.Read();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                var isReaderNull = (reader[0].GetType() == typeof(DBNull));

                if (!isReaderNull)
                    result = reader[0].ToString();
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("An error occurred while As400 Synchronizer (NumberOfRow): ", ex);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I expect only PCIMPF to be used.

Comment: PC05L looks like a logical file(Index). Check with AS400 system administrator to confirm that PC05L is logical file defined on table PCIMPF.  Database might use logical file(index) defined on the table during SQL execution to improve performance.  Using logical file (index) is decided automatically by database optimizer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the difference from logical and physical file?

Comment: @MatteoScattolin although StackOverflow is educational it is not a substitute for learning. Study the documentation on this topic and related topics at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzasc/sc092507380.htm#hpflf

Comment: Ok, sorry. Thanks